# how to pass many2one object in xmlrpc for openerp

Tags: python, django, odoo, xml-rpc

I have django as front-end app, where I am saving "res.partner" id relating to django user.  Based on that id I am fetching "res.partner" object from openerp. Now I want pass that "res.partner" object to openerp field having many2one relation, using xmlrpc. All other fields along with this object is being saved but not this object. Can you please guide me how to pass object in xmlrpc for openerp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass id value (db id field) to the field(many2one).

Please check documentation [here](https://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/developer/12_api/)

In the doucmentation you can see partner_id is created and the id field is returned there

```
import xmlrpclib

sock = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy('http://localhost:8069/xmlrpc/object')
uid = 1
pwd = 'demo'

partner = {
    'title': 'Monsieur',
    'name': 'Fabien Pinckaers',
    'lang': 'fr',
    'active': True,
}

partner_id = sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'res.partner', 'create', partner)

address = {
    'partner_id': partner_id,
    'type': 'default',
    'street': 'Rue du vieux chateau, 21',
    'zip': '1457',
    'city': 'Walhain',
    'phone': '(+32)10.68.94.39',
    'fax': '(+32)10.68.94.39',
}

sock.execute(dbname, uid, pwd, 'res.partner.address', 'create', address)
```

Comment: Thanks senthilnathang, it works for me... Thanks for your help and time.